# Spark Delta Lake crea muchos archivos .parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Estoy intentando hacer un upsert endeltalake

```
val updatesDF = ...  // define the updates DataFrame[date, eventId, data]

DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/data/events/")
  .as("events")
  .merge(
    updatesDF.as("updates"),
    "events.eventId = updates.eventId")
  .whenMatched
  .updateExpr(
    Map("data" -> "updates.data"))
  .whenNotMatched
  .insertExpr(
    Map(
      "date" -> "updates.date",
      "eventId" -> "updates.eventId",
      "data" -> "updates.data"))
  .execute()
```

Pero este escribe muchos archivos .parquet (1 por cada fila!) ¿que puede estar pasando?

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, traduce tu pregunta, el idioma oficial del sitio es el "español", saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Spark si tiene algún tipo de shuffle (`groupBy`, `join` etc) reparte tus datos en particiones. Por defecto spark pone 200 particiones, pero se puede configurar con la opción `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. Estas particiones son el número de tareas que divide el job (trabajo) en un stage o etapa, y si este stage es el último, escribirá 200 ficheros.

Reduce este valor y escribirá un menor número de ficheros.